# How to create a full desktop based on a tiling wm?

Tags: window-manager

I want to install a tiling wm like Xmonad based on a minimal installation with Ubuntu mini.iso. I've already done this.

But I miss a lot of features like multimedia keys (volume), power management (display backlight brightness on my laptop), automountig of USB storage devices and other typical desktop features.

How can I add this features?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using Xmonad.
You might be able to use gnome-flashback along with xmonad, which might solve the problems. However, this approach also has a drawback of being forced with looks of gnome-flashback.

On the other hand, the goal of Xmonad is to have configurable setup where you could modify every behavior including what each keybinding does. Perhaps you could try that and see if you'd like it.

Specifically, the following setup is what I used for backlight brightness and volume control.
(I installed [lux](https://github.com/Ventto/lux) and [pulseaudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/) for this)

```haskell
main :: IO ()
main = do
  xmonad $ def `additionalKeys` [
        ((noModMask, xF86XK_MonBrightnessUp), safeSpawn "lux" ["-a", "5%"])
      , ((noModMask, xF86XK_MonBrightnessDown), safeSpawn "lux" ["-s", "5%"])
      , ((noModMask, xF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume), safeSpawn "pactl" ["set-sink-volume", "0", "+5%"])
      , ((noModMask, xF86XK_AudioLowerVolume), safeSpawn "pactl" ["set-sink-volume", "0", "-5%"])
      , ((noModMask, xF86XK_AudioMute), safeSpawn "pactl" ["set-sink-mute", "0", "toggle"])
    ]
```

You might want to use different software for this purpose.

I do not know why automounting does not work on your computer, likely it is unrelated with window manager. Maybe, try installing the usb drivers?